# Airflow 1.10.10 Changed Graph view

Tags: airflow

I upgraded airflow from 1.10.1 to 1.10.10 and I see graph view has changed a bit.
Earlier the dependencies were shown as curved arrows whereas now it has changed to straight arrows.
Here is the screenshot of it old vs new. I wanted to know if there is any way to get the old view back since its more readable for our internal users.

Old Airflow Graph View -
[image: Old Airflow 1.10.1]

New Airflow Graph View -
[image: New Airflow 1.10.10]

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is documented on [Airflow Bug 6768](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-6768). It seems to be related to an upgrade of the dagre-d3 library used to render the Graph View. So far the bug is unresolved.

I wonder if solution proposed on [this Github issue](https://github.com/dagrejs/dagre-d3/issues/305) could work in Airflow. The idea is to replace the default style of line used in Airflow code manually to d3.curveBasis.

Looking on the codebase, you could try updating this code on [graph.html](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/www/templates/airflow/graph.html) template:

```
// Preparation of DagreD3 data structures
var g = new dagreD3.graphlib.Graph().setGraph({
    nodesep: 15,
    ranksep: 15,
    rankdir: arrange,
  })
  .setDefaultEdgeLabel(function() { return { lineInterpolate: 'basis' } });
```

replacing `lineInterpolate: 'basis'` with `lineCurve: d3.curveBasis`.

Please let us know if this solves the issue to report back to the Airflow bugtracker.

Comment: In airflow v1.10.10 has above function in airflow/www_rbac/templates/airflow/graph.html but changing those values did not work.